# Javascript Objects Clarification

Tags: javascript, object

am a  beginner learning javascript and was playing around with Objects and am wondering why this code is throwing an error.

```
var a =  {
    greeting: "Hello",
    greet: this.greeting +  "John"
}
console.log(a.greet);
```

Comment: It is throwing an error because when you are initializing an object, you cannot reference other fields in that object.

Comment: You cannot use 'this' inside the object creation, a JSON object doesn't exist at this stage.  Also, member names should be encapsulated in quotes.  Try one of the many online JSON validators.

Comment: The above code is not throwing an error, it's rather logging `undefinedJohn`, because the `this` you are using does not refer to `a`, but to `window`.

Comment: It does not trow an error. It just returns undefined for `this.greeting` because this is not defined in the global scope.

Comment: @briosheje it would throw an error in strict mode inside a function.

Comment: @vlaz there is no strict mode in the example provided by the OP though. It's just not throwing an error in that scenario specifically, is it?

Comment: See here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object
and here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Comment: @briosheje OP says they are a novice in JS. I'd cut them some slack in not expanding on the, frankly, a bit obscure and obtuse strict mode. Which they probably don't really know about at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's been clarified *why* your code throws an error, I wanted to explain how you could have it instead.

Javascript makes no difference between ordinary functions and constructors, to a class is just a call to `new function` with any function in front of it.

Therefore, a way the object can reference itself is by using a function body as its definition:

```
const AClass = function () {
  this.greeting = 'Hello'
  this.greet = this.greeting + ' John'
}

const a = new AClass()
console.log(a.greet)
```

Shorthand since you aren't going to create more than one `AClass` object (at least in your example):

```
const a = new function () {
  this.greeting = 'Hello'
  this.greet = this.greeting + ' John'
}()

console.log(a.greet)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @gchiconi, I understand better now

Answer (score 1):

Yours doesn't work because of the problems described in the comments.

I'm guessing that you want something like this:

```js
var a =  {
    greeting: "Hello",
    greet: function() {return this.greeting +  " John"}
}
console.log(a.greet());
```

Or like this:

```js
var a = (() => {
    var greeting = "Hello"
    return {
        greeting,
        greet: greeting + ' John'
    }
})()

console.log(a.greet);
```

The first one makes `greet` a function, which means that it will respond to later changes in `greeting`.  The second one creates an object based on the `greeting` value.  But you have to use a local variable for the reference, since your `this` at the time of construction is not the new object but some outer scope, possibly something like `window`.

Answer (score -1):

This question you have is explained here: [How Do I reference objects proerty at creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824129/how-do-i-reference-the-same-objects-properties-during-its-creation)

In order to do what you want you can use an object getter.

```js
 var b = {
        greeting: "Hello",
        get greet() { //this a getter that accesses greeting
            return this.greeting + " John";
        }
    }
    console.log(b.greet);
```

Comment: While it passes the test and is probably better for a reactive `greeting` property, it does not behave exactly like the proposed code should. One such example is when calling `JSON.stringify` with this object.