# javascript access external variable from object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I properly reference someVar from inside an object? If I prepend it with 'this' I get a 'cannot read property someVar of undefined' error.

```
// Vue code
data:() => ({
  someVar:'foo',
  someObj:{
    someArray:[{baz:this.someVar + 'baz'}],
  },
}),
```

Comment: You cant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824129/how-do-i-reference-the-same-objects-properties-during-its-creation

Comment: Ddefine someVar as a const in your Vue file your